# Setting valid produce and consume media types in swagger for MVC5 in .net Framework 4.7 (NOT ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

I see many examples with ASP.NET Core that explains on how to set valid produces/consumes media types using swagger on ASP.NET Core MVC but I am unable to figure out how should I set the valid produce/consumes media types on MVC 5 running on .net framework 4.7. Please Help.
I tried using [Produces("application/JSON")] attribute but system complains about Produces attribute not found. I think this is specific to mvc in .net core and not for .net framework 4.7. I have installed swashbuckle Nuget package only. Do I need to install any other package?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? What goes wrong?

Comment: I tried using [Produces("application/JSON")] attribute but system complains about Produces attribute not found. I think this is specific to mvc in .net core and not for .net framework 4.7. I have installed swashbuckle Nuget package only. Do I need to install any other package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a variation on this example,
https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/08/04/swashbuckle-pro-tips-for-aspnet-web-api-part-1/
I implemented ProducesAttribute and ConsumesAttribute decorators, and looked for both decorators in an IOperation.Appy filter method.